# AWS Batch job is marked as successful when in fact its log shows that it failed

Tags: python, bash, aws, batch

Tengo un trabajo en AWS Batch, que llama a un archivo .sh que a su vez ejecuta un script de python. El script de python falla con un error de que no encuentra un archivo específico en un directorio, pero, el proceso en AWS Batch termina con éxito, lo que debería ser al revés. ¿Hay algo que deba comprobar?

Comment: Te equivocaste de sitio. Estás en stack overflow en español. Considera eliminar la pregunta y colocarla en el sitio en inglés o editarla y traducirla a español, de lo contrario terminara cerrada.

Comment: O de pronto estás en el sitio correcto y sólo necesitas traducir toda la pregunta a español :D (puedes ir a [edit] para traducir todo, incluyendo el título)